# What are the advantages/disadvantages of separate user & account models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, rails-activerecord

I frequently see programmers separate these, e.g. User `has_one` Account or Profile or whatever. What gives? Is there some security advantage to keeping authentication/authorization separate from other attributes that might much more easily be put into the User model?

I guess more generally, my question is, what is the purpose of a one-to-one `has_one`-`belongs_to` relationship?

I could see the purpose if there were different, interchangeable account types (although you could just have user types, I think), or if a User `has_many` Accounts.

Am I missing something? Why not use one model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some advantages I can think about:

- Separating user & profile make models cleaner, every model will be responsible for only one thing: the user for logging/auth - things that matters for the user himself only; and the profile for information that are viewed on the user's page and matter for everybody.
- As a result, this will make less overhead on the DB. You'll need to access/update `users` table only at logging, and without accessing/updating the (possibly big) data of the user's information that only matter for viewing.
- If you have a developers team responsible for authentication and another responsible for presentation. It's a good idea to separate the resources they're dealing with as much as possible. A thing that deserves mention here is that such kind of separation not only helps in models, but also in controllers and maybe views.
- Another good reason is when you need to give a user more than one profile. Yes that's common if your app is somehow "social". [LinkedIn](https://linkedin.com) allows users to have many profiles, each in a specific language.

Answer (score 1):

Well one big reason is that it is better to separate classes to make your app more manageable.Maybe your user will fill out some profile information after they sign up for your service so having a separate class that handles that is much easier to manage and things get less messy down the line.

Your classes should have one single responsibility and it should be clear what that class does  and be able to fully execute it.This principle is the S in SOLID design principles.You can read more about it here: [SOLID](http://www.sitepoint.com/solid-ruby-single-responsibility-principle/)

Hope this answers some of your questions!

Comment: Thanks for the info on SOLID. I'd encountered most of those principles before, but haven't internalized them to the point that I'm consciously thinking about them when I design software yet. I suppose the reason for my question was that this approach seemed to violate the SRP in that User class separated from its account isn't fully able to execute its task. But I suppose from the perspective of "having only one reason to change" this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It can actually make a significant performance difference in a heavily trafficed website.

Consider a website where people are almost always logged in but rarely access their profile/account. Every time you fetch a user for authentication, you're moving all the profile data in/out/around of memory (you can get around this by telling the fetch to only include certain columns, but that's less maintainable and more prone to accidental screwups than segmenting the model).